# How can I open an iframe automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have two iframes, iframe1 and iframe2. Iframe1 has 4 links. Now when I click on the last link, I have been able to close the iframe. But on closing it, I want iframe2 to be opened without any user-initiated action. How can I achieve this ?

This is the code that I have used for closing iframe1 and then i am trying to call iframe2 like this :

EDIT :

```
function prepareFrame() {
alert("Inside prepare frame");
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "openThis.jsp");
ifrm.style.width = 640+"px";
ifrm.style.height = 480+"px";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}

function closeMyIframe() {
  var parentDynamicDiv = window.parent.document.getElementById('dynamic_id1');
  var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementById('dynamic_id2');
  iframe.style.display = 'none';
  parentDynamicDiv.style.display = 'none';
  prepareFrame();
}
```

Here the alert inside prepareFrame() is coming up but the modal is not .

Iframe1 is sourced from a parent jsp called myJSP.jsp, so when closed, I presume the control returns to that jsp. From there on, how can I open the new iframe automatically?

Kindly help.

Comment: Your question a little meaningful. What is `iframe2`? You did not mention it in the code snippet. Is `iframe2` already existing? Why not hiding it initially and change its display to 'block' in your function?

Comment: Hi armin, edited the question.

Comment: BTW  i am constructing iframe2 using the code in prepareframe()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your iframe1 id is `dynamic_id1`, iframe2 id is `dynamic_id2` and your function `closeMyIframe()` is inside iframe1 page.

If so, just change your code line 4, from

```
iframe.style.display = 'none';
```

to

```
iframe.style.display = 'block';
```